# Connection properties like username and password are getting printed in the Logs without masking. How to mask the password?(in Hibernate 2.1.6)

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

I am using Hibernate 2.1.6 in my project and commons-logging 1.0.4. While running the jar, logs are getting printed in the log file. I am not able to upgrade the Hibernate version nor change the logging tool to log4j. Can anyone help me how to avoid printing username and password?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGEqa.png)

Comment: Configure your logging library to disable logging of that specific logger. That said, Hibernate 2.1.6 is ancient. You really should upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Ancient is right. Released August 2004. If your application's stack is that outdated then outputting passwords to log files probably isn't the only security issue you'll have to tackle

Comment: As said by Mark, disable logging for `net.sf.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer can you please tell me how to disable using commons logging.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Could you please tell me how to disable in commons logging

Comment: Read the documentation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html As an aside, commons-logging is only a facade, so you actually need to configure the underlying logging library you're using.